# Buttons do not change position

Tags: android, xml, button, position

In my XML file everything looks how I want, however in my phone and emulator two buttons swap positions. 
here is my XML(it is long so I am only pasting the related part):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/indexmenu_button"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonChannelList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="" 
                    android:background="@drawable/channelnotselected"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFavoriteChannelList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:text="" 
                    android:background="@drawable/favoritelistnotselected"/>
```

So button "@+id/buttonChannelList" and "@+id/buttonFavoriteChannelList" are correct in XML graphical view and code view, but as I said they swap places in phone and Emulator.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project. I think the same with Caner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why, so maybe you can try `Project -> Clean` and rebuild